# How can I set one NVIDIA graphics card for display and other for computing(in Linux)?

Tags: linux, cuda

I have install NVIDIA display driver and CUDA tookit on my machine with one NVIDIA GT520 card (used for both display and computation) but it is giving me error **"the launch timed out and was terminated"**, for some program. I searched for this error they are saying this error is due to OS watchdog(CentOS 6) and my kernel is taking too much of time. I find one solution that I can insert two cards and I can use one for display and other for computation on [this link](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/521245/the-launch-timed-out-and-was-terminated-strange-error-on-cudamemcpy/). How can I set particular one card for display and other for computation. I have CentOS 6.5 with kernel 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64.

Comment: You can do this via appropriate modification of your `xorg.conf` file.  You might be interested in [this document](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3029/~/using-cuda-and-x).  The question is off-topic for SO, I believe, which is why you have gotten some close votes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A general description of how to do this is given [here](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3029/~/using-cuda-and-x).  You want to use the option 1 which is excerpted below:

Option 1: Use Two GPUs (RECOMMENDED)

If two GPUs can be made available in the system, then X processing can be handled on one GPU while CUDA tasks are executed on the other. This allows full interactivity and no disturbance of X while simultaneously allowing unhindered CUDA execution.

In order to accomplish this:

•The X display should be forced onto a single GPU using the BusID parameter in the relevant "Device" section of the xorg.conf file. In addition, any other "Device" sections should be deleted. For example:

```
    BusID "PCI:34:0:0"
```

The PCI IDs of the GPUs may be determined from the lspci command or from the nvidia-smi -a command.

•CUDA processing should be forced onto the other GPU, for example by using the CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES environment variable before any CUDA applications are launched. For example:

```
    export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="1"
```

(Choose the numerical parameter to select the GPU that is not the X GPU)

Comment: How can I get the numerical rank of GPU which is not the X GPU?

Comment: @krishna use `deviceQuery` sample from CUDA SDK.